# recentf cleanup upon mode enabled: not saved in the actual recentf-save-file

Tags: emacsclient, recentf

When Emacs starts, it reports a non-existent file is removed from recentf. However, that removal was never saved to the `recentf-save-file`: the next time Emacs starts, the same removal is reported again. How can I ask Emacs to actually save that removal to the actual file?

Note: I'm using Emacs server and client.

Comment: Do you see this also when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q`? If not, recursively bisect your init file to see what causes the problem. If yes, consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @Drew It looks like `recentf-save-list` was never called when using Emacs server.

Comment: Like I said, consider `M-x report-emacs-bug`.